# Fill box with random size shapes

Tags: javascript, positioning

I need to fill a box with fixed size, it should be filled with **9** *random* size shapes.

Since I have 9 shapes one or more can be on top of another, the point of this is to create randomness effect as if those shapes are scattered randomly. But then again there can't be any empty space left, that's very important and the most difficult part.

So to imagine what I'm doing better I have and example of how this should loook like

[image]

And I have also setup jsFiddle, you check it out [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/zrNQ4/2/)

I was working on this for hours on this and no matter what i thought of didn't work so this is just a very basic example of what i'm doing with the code.

I'm not asking for a fully working code, but any kind of advice on how should i continue from this point would help a lot.

And since SO rules are asking for jsFiddle code, here it is:

```
$shape = $('<div class="shape"></div>');
$container = $(".container");

//random shape sizes
shapes = [
    [rand(50, 70), rand(50, 70)],
    [rand(50, 70), rand(50, 70)],
    [rand(60, 70), rand(60, 70)],
    [rand(60, 100), rand(60, 100)],
    [rand(100, 140), rand(100, 140)],
    [rand(100, 140), rand(100, 140)],
    [rand(100, 140), rand(100, 140)],
    [rand(140, 190), rand(140, 190)],
    [rand(150, 210), rand(150, 210)]
];

used = [];
left = 0;
top = 0;

for(i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    offset = rand(0, 8);

    width = shapes[offset][0];
    height = shapes[offset][1];

    $container.append(
        $shape.css({
            width: width,
            height: height,
            top: top,
            left: left,
            zIndex: i
        })
        .text(i)
        .clone()
    );

    //increase top offset
    top += shapes[offset][1];
}


function rand(from, to){
    return Math.floor((Math.random()*to)+from);
}
```

Comment: Interesting question (though not an easy one). Before diving into it, I assume boxes _shouldn't_ overlap (in your image they do).

Comment: Also, image cropping is allowed?

Comment: Your implementation of `rand()` is bad. If you have `rand(2,4)` and the random number is `~1` you will get `5`. You could do: `(((from-to)*rand)+from)`

Comment: @sixFingers Well they should not all of them thou, but at least one or two

Comment: @sixFingers Yes, don't care about images, i can deal with them i just need those boxes to be randomly placed, images really doesn't matter

Comment: Could you please share the website you need to use that in? If there's a practical use of such grid, I would enjoy writing a module that does that, if someone else is ever going to need it. That could also solve your question in case you haven't solved it with the proposed solution.

Comment: True randomness isn't required to make something appear random. For example, you could define several layouts, each with a few different sub-layouts; then build the box by randomly choosing the layout and sub-layouts, and adding in a little more minor randomization where possible. It would feel random enough. It depends on what's easier to implement: randomness or an imitation of it.

Comment: @Slytael I'm sorry but i really can't reveal the adress of the project I'm working on

Comment: @MattCoughlin That's an interesting solution, If i can't write a good enough looking algorithm I might end up doing what you said, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the answer is a very difficult one, we could go depp into it as you're in need of some sort of space-filling algorithm.

I'm honestly not that strong into this kind of things, but I would suggest - if you can handle it - into this topics:

- Fractal fill algorithms
- Voronoi cells with centroid relaxation
- Binary trees

I tried instead to write down a simple implementation of the latter, binary tree. It works by subdividing recursively an area of space into smaller pieces.

```
var square = {x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200};
var struct = [square];

function binary(struct) {
    var axis = 1;
    function subdivide(index) {
        var item = struct.splice(index, 1)[0];
        if(axis > 0) {
            var aw = item.width / 2;
            var ow = Math.random() * aw;
            ow -= ow / 2;
            var ax = Math.round(item.width / 2 + ow);
            var bx = item.width - ax;
            struct.push({x: item.x, y: item.y, width: ax, height: item.height});
            struct.push({x: item.x + ax, y: item.y, width: bx, height: item.height});
        } else {
            var ah = item.height / 2;
            var oh = Math.random() * ah;
            oh -= oh / 2;
            var ay = Math.round(item.height / 2 + oh);
            var by = item.height - ay;
            struct.push({x: item.x, y: item.y, width: item.width, height: ay});
            struct.push({x: item.x, y: item.y + ay, width: item.width, height: by});
        }

        axis = -axis;
    }

    while(struct.length < 9) {
        var index = Math.round(Math.random() * (struct.length-1));
        subdivide(index);
    }

    return struct;
}
```

Calling

```
binary(struct);
```

Returns you an array of subdivided regions. Hope this can be a starting point (also I assume you don't want to run a memory-heavy algorithm *only* to place images randomly in a box, but I might be wrong :))

Comment: Wow you are one great guy for writing such an awesome code, and thanks for the info, this is going to help me a lot, btw i have implemented your function and it works great! http://jsfiddle.net/zrNQ4/3/ ofcourse it's still just a half way where i want it to be but now i have something to work on. I will probably leave this question open so i could reward you some rep points, and maybe I'll have some more questions later on lol .

Comment: Happy to help :) I like this kind of algos so i'll look for better implementations and let you know.